# Is there an "operating chain" or "history" in Blender? So I can change the previous settings without affecting the existing action

Tags: python, animation, scripting

example:

Add -> Mesh -> Cylinder

Then I can use "Operator Panel" (**Edit -> Adjust Last Operation** OR hit **F9**) to adjust the parameter of the Cylinder, like Radius, Depth.

[image]

then I assign material to the Cylinder.

Now I want to adjust the parameter again or do something animation with those parameters. what should I do? The panel is gone, hit **F9** and give me another panel. I can't adjust that Cylinder anymore.

[image]

Comment: Once you've set your original parameters and carried out any other operation on the mesh, there's no way of changing the original parameters of the object.

Comment: it's called non-destructive modeling, you could write your own operator that repeats everything on the property change, or you can use geonodes or otherwise modifiers… But you can't go back in time and tell Blender you wanted a different setting on a previous operator.

Comment: AFAIK, the Undo history restores a diff. on the entire file, without isolating operators, which could be seen as a failing, but is simple. It's deep in the system, and, yes, a contrast with some other applications.

Comment: @RobinBetts I think you can turn this feature off, at least that's how I understand the "global undo" - but then probably you can expect some bugs… https://i.imgur.com/dgP1b7P.png

Comment: Hi, @Markus.. is that just a bit-wise or similar diff. v a copy ? I don't know. It would be great to have a definitive answer to this one. It's not a command history, I don't think.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  So, there is a way that I can build my custom operator (use Python API) to animate those parameters after assigning a material to it, right?

Comment: @g2m.agent I'm not sure what you mean by "animate". Take any existing operator, like creating a new cube. Can you animate it? Well, you can slide a setting, and see it update in real-time, with the cuboid seemingly change shape, even though in reality it's a series of undoing the previous operation and running the operator again with new settings. You can achieve exactly same effect by creating your own operator, which under the hood can use multiple operators, e.g. Add new cube + bevel it.

Comment: If you want to render an animation, you can also use Python to automatically run an operator(s) on each frame, with settings depending on the frame number, or you can use something like geometry nodes instead.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady "animate" means adjusting parameters (like height, vertices, radius, vertex colors ... anything that Operator Panel offers.).